# h:selectOneMenu : validation error

Tags: java, jsf-2

I defined the following drop down box in my page:
    ...

```
<td>
  <h:selectOneMenu id="bootenvironment1" value="#{detailModel.selectedBootenvironment1}"
                   disabled="#{detailModel.mode == detailModel.viewMode}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{detailModel.availableBootenvironments}"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
</td>
```

In my model I have:

```
...
  private Map<String, Bootenvironment> availableBootenvironments;

  public DefinitionDetailModel()
  {
    super();
  }

  public String getSelectedBootenvironment1()
  {
    if (((Definition) getAfterObject()).getBootenvironment1() != null)
    {
      return ((Definition) getAfterObject()).getBootenvironment1().getEnvironmentName();
    }

    return "--Please select one--";
  }

  public void setSelectedBootenvironment1( String selectedBootenvironment )
  {
    ((Definition) getAfterObject()).setBootenvironment1(availableBootenvironments.get(selectedBootenvironment));
  }
  ...
```

And in the controller I set the availableBootenvironments map:

```
private void fetchBootenvironments()
  {
    ...
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    List<Bootenvironment> bootenvironments = (List<Bootenvironment>) ...

    Map<String, Bootenvironment> availableBootenvironments = new HashMap<String, Bootenvironment>();

    availableBootenvironments.put("--Please select one--", null);

    for(Bootenvironment bootenvironment : bootenvironments)
    {
      availableBootenvironments.put(bootenvironment.getEnvironmentName(), bootenvironment);
    }

    ((DefinitionDetailModel) detailModel).setAvailableBootenvironments(availableBootenvironments);
  }
```

The problem is that when I click a button in the page (which is bound to an action), I get the error:

> detailForm:bootenvironment1: Validation error: value is not valid.

I don't understand where the error is; the *value* for *selectItems* is a map with the object's name-field(so a string) as key and the object itself as value. Then the *value* for the default selected (`value="#{detailModel.selectedBootenvironment1}"`) is a string too as you can see in the getter/setter method of the model.

Another problem (maybe related to the previous one) is that when the page first loads, the default selected value should be --Please select one--- as the *getBootenvironment1()* returns *null*, but this does not happen: another one from the list is selected.

Can you please help me understanding what/where am I doing wrong?

EDIT

I implemented the Converter as you said:

```
@FacesConverter( forClass = Bootenvironment.class )
public class BootenvironmentConverter implements Converter
{

  @Override
  public String getAsString( FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue ) throws ConverterException
  {
    return String.valueOf(((Bootenvironment) modelValue).getDbId());
  }

  @Override
  public Object getAsObject( FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue ) throws ConverterException
  {
    List<Bootenvironment> bootenvironments = ... (get from DB where dbid=submittedValue)

    return bootenvironments.get(0);
  }

}
```

But now I have the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   ch.ethz.id.wai.bootrobot.bo.Bootenvironment

Comment: Maybe your are getting an NPE because the  `getAfterObject()` is null and the getter: `getSelectedBootenvironment1()` doesn't return a valid value for your  `selectOneMenu`  `value` property. Try to check `getAfterObject()` [in `getSelectedBootenvironment1()`] against null before accessing its `getBootenvironment1()`method

Comment: I checked and getAfterObject() is not null...

Comment: So the next thing is: does `getBootenvironment1().getEnvironmentName()` always return a non-null object? (presumably `String`)

Comment: When I debug, inside getSelectedBootenvironment1() I see that it doesn't go inside the if (meaning that ((Definition) getAfterObject()).getBootenvironment1() returns null) as it should be. So the method returns "--Please select one--" as expected....

Comment: @pankar: the map key is the option label, not the option value. So this is never been passed back to the server. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get this error when the selected item value doesn't pass the `equals()` test on any of the available item values.

And indeed, you've there a list of `Bootenvironment` item values, but you've bound the property to a `String` which indicates that you're relying on the `Bootenvironment#toString()` value being passed as submitted value and that you aren't using a normal JSF `Converter` at all. A `String` can never return `true` on an `equals()` test with an `Bootenvironment` object.

You'd need to provide a `Converter` which converts between `Bootenvironment` and its unique `String` representation. Usually, the technical ID (such as the autogenerated PK from the database) is been used as the unique `String` representation.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Bootenvironment.class)
public class BootenvironmentConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public void getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) throws ConverterException {
        // Write code to convert Bootenvironment to its unique String representation. E.g.
        return String.valueOf(((Bootenvironment) modelValue).getId());
    }

    @Override 
    public void getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object submittedValue) throws ConverterException {
        // Write code to convert unique String representation of Bootenvironment to concrete Bootenvironment. E.g.
        return someBootenvironmentService.find(Long.valueOf(submittedValue));
    }

}
```

Finally, after implementing the converter accordingly, you should be able to fix the `selectedBootenvironment1` property to be a normal property without any mess in getter/setter:

```
private Bootenvironment selectedBootenvironment1;

public Bootenvironment getSelectedBootenvironment1() {
    return selectedBootenvironment1;
}

public void setSelectedBootenvironment1(Bootenvironment selectedBootenvironment1) {
    this.selectedBootenvironment1 = selectedBootenvironment1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you BalusC; one more question: how do I have to define the controller then in the page? simply <h:selectOneMenu ... converter="BootenvironmentConverter"?

Comment: Ok. I found out how to define it, but now I have another problem: see edit in question.

Comment: You don't need to define it in the view. The `@FacesConverter(forClass=Bootenvironment.class)` takes care that it will automatically be applied whenever a `Bootenvironment` is encountered as model value.

Comment: As to your class cast exception; where exactly is this been thrown?

Comment: But do I have to define it in the faces-config.xml?

Comment: No, the `@FacesConverter` part auto-registers the converter class, like as `@ManagedBean` does it for managed bean classes.

Comment: Ok. The error was elsewhere. I fixed it and now it works! :) Thank you very much! Now another problem: the bootenvironment is part of another Object(Definition). Now, I can create or edit a definition. I would like to have that when I create a new Definition, the default value in the dropdown is --Please select one--, but if I edit it, it should show the already associated one. Is this possible?

Comment: That's just a label. Your current code shows that it has a value of `null`. So if you just make it `null` then the corresponding label will be shown. Please note that you shouldn't put any clutter in getter/setter of the property, as mentioned in my answer. Just let the getter return the property and let the setter set the property. For the default selection, just rely on `null` as default. That's all.